# what is branch coverage?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, istqb, certification

I am preparing myself for ISTQB exam and I came across this question.

> For the code fragment given below, which answer correctly represents
>   minimum tests required for statement and branch coverage respectively?
>
> ```
> Discount rate=1;
> Fare = 1000;
> If ((person == “senior citizen”) and (“travel month = January”))
> Bonuspoints = 100+Bonuspoints
> If (class==”first”)
> discountRate = .5;
> Fare = fare * discountRate;
> ```
>
> - a. Statement Coverage = 1, Branch Coverage = 2
> - b. Statement Coverage = 2, Branch Coverage = 2
> - c. Statement Coverage = 1, Branch Coverage = 3
> - d. Statement Coverage = 2, Branch Coverage = 4

Answer is **A**

But my answer is **C** the reason is flowchart I draw for it given below.

1. Straight forward from start to end
2. One false for 1st 'if'
3. second false for 2nd 'if'

[image: Flow chart]

My question is:

1. Should we draw an edge 'explicitly' for 'false' condition, if it is not given in question itself.
2. How branch coverage is 3 here ?

Comment: Related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20226/how-do-we-calculate-statement-coverage-branch-coverage-path-coverage-and-cond